# Map a procedural texture like an image texture

Tags: materials

Is it possible to map a procedural texture like an image texture?

Image textures have the posibility to be mapped **flat, cubic, spherical** etc.

Can I take for example the **x and y** part of a procedural and map it cubic, so this x and y canvas is mapped equaly to every side of a cube?

EDIT:
Sorry qeustion was asked wrong: I wanted this for Cycles Renderer.

Comment: Answer updated to include cycles in the mix

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Blender Internal**:

Yes, procedural textures can be projected the same way as image textures. In the texture tab, scroll down the procedural texture's settings to the Mapping group. You can find the projection and axes drop downs there.

[image]

**Cycles**:

Cycles does not offer shape projections (cube / sphere / tube / flat), but using but a Texture Coordinate Input node set to Generated or Object, and a Vector Mapping node, a similar effect can be achieved. Just play with the scale and rotation values to fine-tune the effect:

[image: Cycles]

Comment: Years of Blender and I never found this... Sorry just tried out but it seems not available for Cycles?

Comment: The cube/sphere/tube/flat projections aren't available in cycles. In all honesty I've never found them extremely useful. You can get the same effect in cycles using the Object or Generated mapping options in the Texture coordinates nodes, and the Vector Mapping node. If you're unfamiliar with this technique, I can add this to my answer.

Comment: Imo it does not answer the question cause how this solves mapping for example Brick texture to the cube in a way of box? The texture wont be applied the same way on all the faces and that was the question - or not?