# How to map the displacement texture?

Tags: modifiers, edit-mode, displacement

I've added the ***Displacement Modifier*** to my object with a ***Wood texture*** for displace. How to change its location, rotation and scale (like you can do with image textures: [Map a procedural texture like an image texture](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/40747/map-a-procedural-texture-like-an-image-texture))? There are no mapping options in the *Displace* texture panels. I'd like to rotate the pattern pictured below, so it's mapped verticaly. How to achieve this?
[image]

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The easiest way to do this is with an empty (empties can be thought of as an object that only stores loc, rot, and scale).

In the modifier, just switch the type to object, and then specify an empty in the drop-down box.

[image]

Here is an example blend:

[image]

Comment: Thank you. I still wonder why I haven't found it by myself :). This is what I need.

Answer (score 4):

If I got what you asked, you can do something (little) mapping the displacement as UV, then unwrapping the displaced mesh, and setting the mesh UV as modifier target. Then (eg) rotating the UV, the displacement rotates. Scaling the UV, the displacement scales.

eg:

[image]

[image]

then rotating the UV:

[image]

[image]

while to scale it on the mesh (horizontally, on the displaced surface, here a simple plane):

[image]

[image]

To scale it vertically, of course you just need to set the modifier's "strength".

Of course you can also see the edits in realtime, setting the modifier to adjust the edit cage to the modifier result:

[image]

Comment: In that case it could be faster to set the modifier's settings to Object and point it to that plane as well.

Comment: Uh, yes, also to an empty, eg. True :) but using an object you get the object mode transforms, while using the UV you can also play with part of the UV vertices, and get interesting (ie: weird) results on the modifier... but that's just a secondary effect...

Comment: Thanks man! Cool solution though I wanted to apply it to sphere, so pycoder's solution is better in my case.

Comment: Good! Of course using a simple object is better, but when I tried the UV option, I started wondering which possibilities could give to adapt, through the UV mesh, the displacement deformation to specific parts of your mesh... someday I'll have to play with this... but I also guess the UV grid can't be animated on its own...

Comment: @m.ardito I see many possibilities to use your method in future. BTW I guess UV grid can be animated via *AnimAll* add-on.